# How to turn off red underlines in comments in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, spell-checking

There is a similar question : "Netbeans - Turn off - wavy red underlines - How?" But It's for earlier version, doesn't apply any more.

I still want error to be underlined, just not in the comments, it's now underlined something like : "buffersize"

Answer (score 28):

In **NetBeans** IDE 7.4 <sub>RC1 (Build 201309162201)</sub>, you can **disable spellchecking** under
Tools → Options → Editor → **Spellchecker** tab

The settings refer to:

- C/C++/Fortran Comments
- GSP
- HTML
- JSP
- Javadoc comments
- PHP
- Piain text
- Properties
- Script and Make Comments
- XHTML
- XML

Screenshot:

[image: NetBeans: Disable/Enable spellchecker]

---

Here is an example [BEFORE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9Wp6.png) and [AFTER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wuq8j.png) disabling HTML spellchecking.

before:

[image: NetBeans: BEFORE disabling HTML spellchecking]

after:

[image: NetBeans: AFTER disabling HTML spellchecking]

Answer (score 3):

This is explained and illustrated in [How to disable red-underline spellchecker in Netbeans 7](http://imelwa.wordpress.com/2011/04/22/how-to-disable-red-underline-spellchecker-in-netbeans-7/):

> To remove it simply choose Tools → Options → Miscellanous, then in
>   Spellchecker tab uncheck the C/C++/Fortran Comments and press OK. [...]
>
> [image: NetBeans - disable spellchecker: Tools -> Options -> Miscellanous -> Spellchecker tab]

The specific result of disabling the spellchecker depends on the target language/syntax of course, but likely this should yield the desired effect.

Answer (score 2):

In Netbeans 12.0 this option can be found under the Editor tab. Not in the Miscellaneous tab.

Goto

> Options -> Tools -> Editor -> SpellChecker Tab

Rest is the same as the first answer.

[image]